# Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?

Tags: iphone, input, uitextfield, uitextview

In my app I want the user to type names into a UITextField (or equivalent) and then when they press return, it will put that word(s) in a blue bubble that's usually associated with tags. The cursor then moves to the end where they can add more "tags".

This can be seen when adding contacts in the To, CC & BCC fields in the Mail app, and also when selecting contacts in the Messages app.

How is this done? Is it something that's provided in the UIKit or available somewhere else?

Many thanks,

Michael

Comment: You might also take a look at [TITokenField](https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField).

Comment: I came across this one that looks good: https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField but I didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 8):

Venmo just open sourced their token field.

https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField.git

Answer (score 6):

**edited:**

The equivalent control in desktop Cocoa is an [`NSTokenField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstokenfield), but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Cocoa Touch.

Comment: That's for Cocoa (OS X), not Cocoa Touch (iPhone)

Comment: Argh. So it is. Sorry about that.

Comment: Simple mistake. Maybe in 4.0 :)

Comment: They don't know how to do it at apple headquarters, they just made a meeting with their engineers, they have drafted a plan to implement for 30 years, in order to obtain a stable tag input control :)

Comment: Keep hoping.. Let the prayers continue ;)

Comment: Had to dust off my time machine to peep at iOS 42 SDK. Lots of cool new features, like running Xcode on Apple Watch, but still no UITokenField.

Comment: Maybe in 12.0 :ooo

Comment: Maybe in 13.0 

Comment: Maybe in 14.3.1   >:-(

Comment: Maybe in 15.0 

Comment: UISearchTextField is the current answer from Apple. See my answer...

Comment: maybe in 16.0 :'-(

Answer (score 3):

Since iOS 13 there exists `UISearchTextField`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchtextfield

You can see that component in action in the Photos App.
That should fit for many use cases. By removing the `leftView` you can also get rid of the search icon.

But be aware: You can‘t mix text and tokens at various positions.

From the docs:

> Tokens always occur contiguously before any text in the search field.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this here for reference:

Feel free to check out [TaggerKit](https://github.com/nekonora/TaggerKit) (a library I made), it's more or less what OP was talking about. You can basically add tags functionality to your app by just adding a view and a couple of properties.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can do it with any built in functionality in the SDK, never seen such a feature. What you could do however is implement it yourself, have some custom blue button with some text over it, and when the user hits return you can have some code that takes the text and returns  you the button that you need, shouldnt be too bad to implement