# [iPhone SDK]How to create a "To:"-Field like in mail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

does anyone know, how I can create a Textfield, like the "To" Field in Mail?
I mean a field, where you can start typing the contacts name and all possible contacts appear in a List under your textfield. And when you select an entry, the entry is entered in your Textfield and shown as some sort of bubble.
Has anyone an idea how to do that, an tutorial or something like that?

Thank you so much

twickl

Comment: Hi twickl. I voted to close, since this question has already been asked. The other question probably didn't show up in your search results because it calls them "tags" instead of "bubbles", I only happened to know about it because I answered the other question myself (incorrectly, sadly). If it helps any, the desktop Cocoa equivalent of that control is called an NSTokenField. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/how-are-tags-used-in-apps-like-mail-and-messages

Comment: How can I close this question und mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question is answerd in the Comment of my First Post!