# Creating a UITextField that works like the iOS Mail's "To" field

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

In iOS's Mail app, when you enter in the email of someone who is in your contact list it formats the text in an interactive bubble. I can't seem to find any obvious way to do this, and it's exactly what my app needs to do, and I'm not even sure where to start.

Any pointers to where to look would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1307553/187118)

Short answer, no, nothing public.

Comment: Unfortunately, inside the link you posted, clicking TTPickerTextField only leads to 404 page not found.

Comment: @OrShanoon https://github.com/facebookarchive/three20/blob/cc672132abf4539e2fa61b2b9f382fb3e88dc49a/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTPickerTextField.h should work.