# IOS: displaying selected items from a UITableView to a UItextField when select

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a project in which I have a category list of items which I display in a `UITableView` and also I am using a `UITextField` to show the selected items from `UITableView`.
The problem is that when I select any row only one item is showing in the `UITextField` but I want to show more than 1 items in `UITextField` with Delete button by which I can remove the selected item from the `TextField`.
I am sharing the screen-shot of the project idea what I want to implement
please help
[image] [image]

Comment: [probably duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915737/creating-a-uitextfield-that-works-like-the-ios-mails-to-field) seems to answer what u would like to achieve

Comment: You can check this library : https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField or https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField

Comment: u need to add uibutton as a subview or u can use uicollectionview for this purpose write any thing on uitextfield and show record in button or uicollectionview cell which should be above of uitextfield. ..Or use uistackview for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can do this way also add text of each row of `uitableview` in an `nsarray` and then that array convert into `nsstring` and then display that string into the textfield.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == itemTable)
    {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [itemTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if([itemArray containsObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text])
        {
            [itemArray removeObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text];

        }
        else
        {

            [itemArray addObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text];
            NSLog(@"%@", selectedCell.textLabel.text);

        }
        NSString *str = [itemArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        elementsField.text = str;
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
       [itemTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        elementsView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```