# UITextfield with behavior like the "to:" UItextfield in email.app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uikit, uitextfield

I would like to have an effect like the to: UITextfield in apples email app.
If an E-Mail Adress is entered completely, it ist replaced by an element in rounded corners.
How can I achieve a behavior like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control :also shows some interestin looking solutions to this Problem

Answer (score 1):

There is a control similar to this that is part of the Three20 library `TTMessageController`

http://three20.info/

https://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: thanks,
does anyone know a good introduction or turorial for tree20?

Answer (score 0):

In OSX NSTokenField adresses this, unfortunately it´s not availible in iOS.
[Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control) also showes some intersting solutions to the Problem.