# Is there an existing iOS component to type in a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control)

I want the user to be able to enter tags in and have them become "units". The screenshot below is from Sparrow.app on OS X, but it gives the idea of what I'm looking for. Is there an existing component that does this? Searching for UITextView and tag doesn't lead to much.

Update: Oh yeah, StackOverflow does this too:

[image: SO example]

[image: Example from Sparrow.app]

Comment: You're looking for the equivalent of [`NSTokenField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/) on iOS. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control has the answer.