# Creating tags for a text field in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a way to create tags (just like here on stackoverflow when you post a question) in xcode/obj-c?

I would like to have a text field where the user can add some predetermined tags to classify something.

Since I haven't started writing this, phonegap is also an option- perhaps it is easier to use tags like that in html?

Anyone have any links or tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac version of this control is called an `NSTokenField`. There's a conversation about an iOS version of this control over here: [Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control)

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5. Alternative solution**

1.Converting Strings to Labels

2.Customizing Labels

3.Converting Labels to Images

4.Converting Images to Attributed text

5.Creating TextView

6.Setting Attributed text to TextView

You can find **implementation** here:

https://github.com/vivatum/WordsAsTagLabels-Example

[image: Final label]

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI tag text field that supports iOS13+.

https://github.com/lijin88121/TagTextField

[image]