# How to Create an iOS search similar to Path's?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am looking to create some sort of search view controller that searches a tableview of names. What I want is very similar to the implementation found in the Path app. It starts out looking similar to the UISearchViewController, except that the search bar at the top is not the standard bar:
[image: path search]

Then, when you select a name from your search, it appears surrounded in a blue bubble (like apple's mail app) and gives you the option to add more people like this:
[image: multiple names]

Does anybody know how this behavior can be recreated? I feel like it might be something in uikit as they use the same blue bubble's in the mail app, but perhaps it is not.

Regardless, I would really appreciate knowing how this is done.

Thanks,

Comment: The blue box is custom. Other than that is is just a UITableView with a header view for the search field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control)

Comment: On a side note, Isn't the Path app awesome?  I don't use it much but they have some really good UI developers over there.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess it is custom. It doesn't seem like it would be that hard to duplicate, so i'm going to give it a shot

Comment: One more question, do you guys know if it is possible to customize the uisearchbar to look plain or to just use a textview instead?