# Name input like SMS or Facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, uitextfield

I'm trying to find a library that can handle autocompletion with tokened (grouped) texts.

There are some very nice libraries out there for autocompletion such as:

https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField
https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField
https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView

The problem here is, I want to make the selection look like names tagging at SMS or Facebook app. So when the user tries to delete, he should delete all the text.

There are good jQuery implementations, one of them is this:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

I couldn't find any for iOS, perhaps the keywords are very generic, thus Google does not show any related results. Is there any library for this or can you provide any code examples?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve can't be done using the public SDK.
However, there exist some nice third party solutions.
I found this question, [Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control), which includes links to controls you could use.