# Tags in Search Bar with Swift

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

In the iOS photos app, after I search 'September', I can press on it in the list, and then it adds a tag to the search bar (like in the image)
[image]

How can I do something like that in my app using `Swift`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppKit we have [NSTokenField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/views_and_controls/token_field) for something like that. Apple apparently hasn't released an equivalent for iOS that can be used out of the box at this time. There seem to be a couple of custom implementations though you might want to check out.

- https://github.com/nekonora/TaggerKit
- https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField
- https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFTokenField
- https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField

[Is there an iPhone equivalent to the NSTokenField control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307553/is-there-an-iphone-equivalent-to-the-nstokenfield-control)
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nstokenfield+ios